# noun + the + adjective

Tags: compound-adjectives

We learned in school that in English always "adjective +noun".But in "Cyrus the great" or "Alexander the great" is "noun+the+adjective". What is the name of the phrase? When could we use that phrase?

Answer (score 1):

This use of an adjective is called an *[epithet](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epithet#Linguistics)* or *byname*, or if you want to get technical about it, the Latin term *epitheton necessarium*. That simply means the epithet is necessary to specify which particular person is meant. Grammatically, it is considered a restrictive appositive.

English and French [*Charlemagne*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlemagne) is actually a contracted form of the French *Charles le Magne*, Charles the Great. This tells you that even non-contracted forms of such epithets function as proper names.

Just like proper names, epithets are always capitalized:

> *Alexander the Great, Richard the Lionheart, Henry the Eighth, Charles the Fat, Charles the Bald*

These last two Carolingians should also tell you that most but not all such epithets become popular after the death of the ruler so designated.